# Django rest framework creating Orders and order items

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I want to create a Order and order items.
For this i am simply creating new model object in views.py using CreateApiView but i am receiving error that "Serializer_class" should be included but i don't need serializer for this.

//views.py

```
class CreateOrder(CreateAPIView):
        def Post(self,request):
            header_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
            print(header_token)
            access_token = header_token.split(' ')[1]
            status,user  = validate_token(access_token)
            cart=Cart.objects.get(user=user)
            print(cart)
            if cart:
                total=cart.total
                userprofile=UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
                order,created=Order.objects.get_or_create(billing_profile=userprofile,total=total)
    
            cart_items=CartItem.objects.get(cart=cart)
            print(cart_items)
            for item in cart_items:
                itemid=item.item_id
                qty=item.quantity
                item_instance = Items.objects.get(item_id=item)
                order_item,created = OrderItems.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=item_instance,quantity=qty)
                order.save()
                order_item.save()
                if created:
                    item.delete()
            return Response (status=rt_status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I want to understand how to achieve this with or without serializer

Comment: You should be able to fix this by extending the `ApiView` class and not the `CreateAPIView` class, also your method name should be `post` Note: all lower case. You can read more on that [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views)

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the incorrect `post` method. If you look at the source code of `CreateAPIView` you will see the method named as shown below.

```
class CreateAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for creating a model instance.
    """
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

NOTE: The method is all lower case.

This method calls `self.create` which is derived from the `CreateModelMixin` and this method needs a serializer.

If you need something light weight where a serializer is not needed I would suggest using `APIView`.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class CreateOrder(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        ....
```